# Just how gaseous is the "gaseous form" of the Wind Walk spell?

Tags: dnd-5e, spells

The [*Wind Walk*](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/wind-walk) spell allows creatures to assume a "gaseous form" that enables them to fly very quickly:

> You and up to ten willing creatures you can see within range assume a gaseous form for the duration, appearing as wisps of cloud. While in this cloud form, a creature has a flying speed of 300 feet and has resistance to damage from nonmagical weapons. The only actions a creature can take in this form are the Dash action or to revert to its normal form.

Unlike the spell whose actual name is *Gaseous Form*, the gaseous form of *Wind Walk* doesn't say anything about various abilities that might be enabled by being non-solid, such as entering another creature's space or squeezing through small cracks. However, many of these abilities are implied by the term "gaseous form", even if you don't read it as a reference to the spell of the same name.

So, does *Wind Walk* actually make an affected creature non-solid and allow them to do anything a gas could, similar to *Gaseous Form*? Other than a very fast fly speed, what additional abilities, if any, are granted to a creature by *Wind Walk*?

Comment: Related on [Spells do what they say](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/107637/what-is-the-source-of-the-spells-do-only-what-they-say-they-do-rules-interpret).

Comment: Maybe a better way to word this would be to ask what mechanical implications the "gaseous form" has, if any?

Comment: I think the wording heavily implies that :) I'm repped out for the day, so just putting up relevant links folks may be interested in when answering.

Answer (score 6):

## *Wind walk* does not grant the effects of [*gaseous form*](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/gaseous-form)

The effects of *wind walk* do not reference the spell effects.  Contrast it to something like a [*potion of gaseous form*](https://www.dndbeyond.com/magic-items/potion-of-gaseous-form) (*Dungeon Master's Guide*, p. 187) which explicitly states it grants the effects of the spell:

> When you drink this potion, you gain the effect of the *gaseous form* spell for 1 hour (no concentration required) [...]

[*Wind walk*](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/wind-walk) only does what it states.  It grants damage resistance, fly speed, and defines the actions that the affected character can take.

Comment: So "assuming a gaseous form" has no mechanical implications?

Comment: @RyanThompson I'd expect advantage on hiding in a fog.

Answer (score 3):

### You *probably* don't get any extra abilities

In your question, you note that the spell *Gaseous Form* explicitly spells out what abilities are gained by not being solid, while *Wind Walk* does not. NautArch also added a link in comments that [spells do what they say they do](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/107637/what-is-the-source-of-the-spells-do-only-what-they-say-they-do-rules-interpret). Since there are other abilities that *explicitly* give you those properties, and since this one *does not*, then it is very likely that you only gain exactly the properties described in *Wind Walk*.

### On the other hand...

That said, you *are* explicitly stated to "assume a gaseous form", and the GM *could* interpret that to mean "with all the traits that a gaseous form would have." This is technically also RAW, even if the spell doesn't *explicitly* spell out what a gaseous form is or what it does. This is also (I think) more likely to be the players' interpretation, as well as being a more common sense interpretation of "assume a gaseous form". That said, DnD is certainly not a physics simulator, so common sense doesn't necessarily matter.

### By strict RAW, I don't think you get any other abilities

But...

### I would give you all the properties of a gas - minus the tendency to diffuse

I think this fits the common sense definition of assuming a gaseous form, and it's still a RAW interpretation. It also allows the players to do some fun stuff and be rewarded for trying something really clever!