# How does the Gaseous Form spell interact with the grappled and restrained conditions?

Tags: dnd-5e, spells, grapple, conditions

Among other things, the [*Gaseous Form*](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/gaseous-form) spell allows a creature to

> pass through small holes, narrow openings, and even mere cracks

The spell does not explicitly make the creature immune to the grappled or restrained conditions, so presumably despite being gaseous, the creature can still be grappled or restrained. However, it seems that the ability to pass through small cracks unimpeded would enable a gaseous creature to escape from any non-airtight mundane restraint in a manner similar to *Freedom of Movement*, since the spaces between a person's fingers and the rings of a pair of manacles would both seem to fit the above definition of what the creature is able to pass through.

So, can a creature affected by *Gaseous Form* be grappled or restrained? If so, can it escape from a non-magical, non-airtight grapple or restraint using its ability to pass through small spaces?

Comment: As might be imagined, this came up while I was comparing the texts of *Wind Walk* and *Gaseous Form* for [this other question](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/147331/just-how-gaseous-is-the-gaseous-form-of-wind-walk).

Answer (score 3):

## You are substantial enough to be attacked by mundane weapons, so you are substantial enough to be restrained/grappled

I understand that this seems illogical to grapple a gaseous form, but the primary problems are that it doesn't state immunity to those conditions and that the form itself is mechanically able to be interacted in a mundane manner via attacks.

There is nothing in *gaseous form* that states it makes you immune to either Grappled or Restrained conditions and spells do what they say and no more.

**Because it doesn't state that it provides immunity to those conditions, then it doesn't provide immunity to those conditions.**

### Mundane interaction with the *gaseous form*

While the spell does state that worn/carried objects can't be interacted with, it does not say that the creature can't be interacted with. In fact it also states that it is susceptible to mundane damage:

> The target has resistance to nonmagical damage...
>
> While in the form of a misty cloud, the target can't talk or manipulate objects, and any objects it was carrying or holding can't be dropped, used, or otherwise interacted with. The target can't attack or cast spells.

If you can still be bludgeoned, pierced, or slashed while in gaseous form, then it's not unreasonable to also allow being grappled or restrained. There is clearly enough substantial matter left.

It's weird to think about, but while in gaseous form the target can still be grappled or restrained - just like it can be hurt by a mundane weapon.

### What about the clause regarding openings/cracks?

To answer your concern quoted in the question regarding cracks/narrow openings, the problem isn't that it can use those - the problem is that you have no movement to use them.

If you are under the effects of [Grappled](https://www.dndbeyond.com/sources/basic-rules/appendix-a-conditions#Grappled)/[Restrained](https://www.dndbeyond.com/sources/basic-rules/appendix-a-conditions#Restrained), then your speed is zero. If your speed is zero, then you can see those opening/cracks, but you can't utilize them to escape.

> A grappled creature's speed becomes 0, and it can't benefit from any bonus to its speed.
>
> A restrained creature's speed becomes 0, and it can't benefit from any bonus to its speed.

Without being able to move due to having their speed set to 0, they simply can't take advantage of those small openings.

It's not that they are paralyzed and can't do anything, it's just that if they are under those conditions, then they have no speed and therefore no movement to leave. The only way they can leave is by first removing the condition or by moving without using movement (*misty step*, *dimension door*, etc.)

### Counterexample: *[freedom of movement](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/freedom-of-movement)*

Had the rules allowed for immunity to these conditions, they could have utilized the language found in the spell *freedom of movement*:

> The target can also spend 5 feet of movement to automatically escape from nonmagical restraints, such as manacles or a creature that has it grappled.

Without the use of this, or any other, clause, the implication is that the normal rules apply.

### Counterexample: Monsters

There are [monsters](https://www.dndbeyond.com/monsters?filter-type=0&filter-search=&filter-cr-min=&filter-cr-max=&filter-armor-class-min=&filter-armor-class-max=&filter-average-hp-min=&filter-average-hp-max=&filter-is-legendary=&filter-has-lair=&filter-condition-immunity=6) that are immune to the grappled condition. Many of them have similar 'properties' to that of *gaseous form* (air elemental, i'm looking at you), but each of them specifically state they are immune to the **grappled** condition.

It is that listed immunity which provides the immunity. Without it...they aren't.

As another example here, the [gray ooze](https://www.dndbeyond.com/monsters/gray-ooze) can fit with openings as narrow as 1 inch without squeezing. And it's an ooze. And this ooze can be grappled.

### How can it escape?

The same way every other [grappled](https://www.dndbeyond.com/sources/basic-rules/combat#ActionsinCombat) creature can. They can either magically move themselves with an action/bonus action with spells like *misty step* or *dimension door*, or they can use their action to try and break the grapple with a contested ability check.

> A grappled creature can use its action to escape. To do so, it must succeed on a Strength (Athletics) or Dexterity (Acrobatics) check contested by your Strength (Athletics) check.

Being able to pass through small openings doesn't give you a free grapple removal (if it did, it would say so as in the *freedom of movement* spell.) It enables you to pass through small openings when you actually have movement to pass through them.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/100455/discussion-on-answer-by-nautarch-how-does-the-gaseous-form-spell-interact-with-t).

Answer (score 1):

## A character in gaseous form can be grappled or restrained, but doesn't have to remain so.

The spell does not specifically grant immunity to the conditions.  So they're not immune to them.  However, it does grant them some methods for readily escaping.

Keeping a character under the effect of gaseous form restrained would require containment that does not have "small holes, narrow openings, nor mere cracks", because the *gaseous form* spell explicitly states that they can move through openings like those.

### Example

Gary the gaseous is escaping from some brutish fellows.

1. Gary casts gaseous form and moves away.
2. A brute grapples Gary, and the fellows move in to attack.
3. Gary's player asks the DM if there are any narrow openings or cracks between the hold the brute has on him.
4. The DM responds with yes.
5. The player states that Gary moves through these as the spell says he can, and removes himself from the grapple.
6. the DM narrates the surprise and confounded look on the brute's face.
7. Gary, being free from the grapple, continues his flight away from the brutes.

This works because having a move speed of 0, as from grappled condition, does not mean the character is paralyzed.  They just cannot move out of their square.  Since passing through the small cracks or openings in the grip of the grappler doesn't require moving out of their square and the spell explicitly allows it, it's hard to keep a gaseous Gary grappled.

Comment: Can you support your 2nd paragraph, especially with the  speed changes from those conditions.

Comment: @NautArch If you can move through whatever is "restraining" you, then it's not restraining you.

Comment: @MarkWells If you're restrained/grappled, then your speed is zero. If your speed is zero, you can't move.

Comment: In your example, how are you utilizing those openings/cracks if your speed is zero from the condition you have?

Comment: Move speed being 0 doesn't mean paralyzed.  With zero move a character still has sufficient mobility to make attacks or interact with objects... or seep through an inch or two of gaps between fingers and arms.

Comment: Except that in gaseous form, you can't attack or manipulate objects.

Comment: That's a result of the spell description, not because of having zero movement.  It does state you can pass through small openings.  As such, that's what Gary does.  He passes through small openings.

Comment: You've got your answer, and i've got mine. I'll stop debating :)

Comment: I tend to agree with @Naut, but I would agree with this answer, too, if it was reframed as "rule of cool."

Comment: @Rykara spells are pretty cool.

Answer (score 1):

I'd use logistics here. The "idea of" the spell is that you're taking a "hazy not entirely stable" form.

Advantage on strength checks: meaning it's harder to do anything physical you, but to "some extent" still possible. The real kicker here however is, you can also "enter and occupy the space of another creature" meaning solids of most any sorts.

Without getting all "rule lawyer" here, I'm going to defer to occam's razor. We're looking at a textbook case of a rose by any other name. Any damage done here is the "concept of disrupting the gaseous cloud" which you become (hence certain weapons and attacks still being somewhat viable), dexterity, constitution checks, etc etc.

I'd rule it becomes "increasingly difficult" to grapple a person as they procedurally become less solid as mist; inevitably grappling attempts would become futile as you can pass through "occupy the space of another creature" other solids in your way. It still hurts through if the person trying to grab you disrupts your haziness by waving their arms or weapons around in the cloud (like waving away a puff of smoke, sitting next to someone whose smoking).

BUT this is just my opinion. If you can distort through cracks, you can distort through a "grip", I mean, you're trying to grab a what is essentially fog here.

In the case of "while in this form, the target's only method of movement is a flying speed of 10 feet." I'd also reason it's "possible" for whatever part of you isn't grappled to "fly" upwards, and flatten (or the equivalent of it) yourself against any ceiling or surface. If the person persists on grappling you, and "somehow" is able to solidly hold mist, they're going to be in for a heck of a fall when they finally fail to hold onto you.

Source: Basic Rules, pg. 244

Comment: Hi Psi, welcome to rpg.se! Take the [tour] and visit the [help] for more information. It would help your answer if you made it clear which parts are quotes from the rules and which are just for emphasis. Use quote block (>), italics (*) and bold (**) to help differentiate them. Also the spell doesn't grant *"Advantage on strength checks"* but saving throws instead. This is a big distinction and one of the reasons it is worth quoting the rule directly. Good luck and happy gaming!